# Javascript error: $(...).observe is not a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-events, tapestry, onkeyup

I'm trying to use [Stitch onEvent mixin](http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/oneventdemo) in Tapestry 5.3.7.

Here's the `OnEvent` Javascript from there:

```
T5.extendInitializers({
   onEvent: function (spec) {
      var element = $(spec.id).observe(spec.event, function () {
         var params = {};
         if (spec.fieldIds) {
            for (var i = 0; i < spec.fieldIds.length; ++i) {
               var fieldId = spec.fieldIds[i];
               var paramName = "onEvent." + fieldId;
               var paramValue = $(fieldId).getValue();
               params[paramName] = paramValue;
            }
         }
         var zoneManager = Tapestry.findZoneManagerForZone(spec.zone);
         zoneManager.updateFromURL(spec.url, params);
      });
   }
});
```

I use it in my TML like this:

```
<t:form t:id="filterTextForm">
    <div style="float:right">
        <input id="filterText" t:id="filterText" t:type="textfield" 
            t:value="filter" zone="configZone" t:autofocus="literal:true" onClick="this.select()" t:mixins="onEvent" event="keyup"/>
    </div>
</t:form>
```

and my event method like this:

```
void onKeyupFromFilterText(String filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
    
    if (request.isXHR()) {
        ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(configZone).addRender(descZone);
    }
}
```

When I have `t:mixins="onEvent" event="keyup"`, none of the zones are updating on the page, no AJAX requests are generated.

When I remove it, everything works fine, except the part I'm trying to do, described in my question.

I'm using Tapestry 5.3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

observe() is a [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) function. I'm guessing that you're using [tapestry-jquery](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/) which is a 3rd party library that removes prototype and replaces it with jquery.

You'll need to adapt the javascript to work with jquery (eg observe() needs to change to [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

You might find other bits of js broken too (eg I'm not sure if tapestry-jquery's ZoneManager is exactly the same as core tapestry).

tapestry-jquery comes with a builtin [bind](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/mixins/docsbind) mixin which does a similar job to `onevent`. You might find it sufficient to use this mixin instead.

Comment: Yes, at one point I did try to switch to jQuery. You said it removes Prototype. Is there a way to get rid of jQuery completely and go back to Prototype?

Comment: Assuming you're building with maven, remove the tapestry-jquery dependency from your pom.xml and do a clean build / deploy

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I've removed all references to jquery from pom.xml and did a clean install, and still to no avail.

When I check it in Firefox debug console, I still see calls to jQuery even though I don't see how.

Comment: I'm using 5.3.7. I've deployed it on Glassfish (3.1.2.2), but the problem is I still see jQuery on classpath (even if there is not a single reference to it in pom.xml).

Comment: Yes, yes and I do not believe so. (None of my searches for "jquery" has returned any results).

Comment: Run ```mvn dependency:tree``` from the command line. Perhaps one of your other dependencies is bringing in ```tapestry-jquery``` as a [transitive dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)

Comment: `$ mvn dependency:tree | grep jquery` returns nothing. I'm even more puzzled now -.-'

Comment: I'm thinking you are doing a dirty deploy to Glassfish. Try seaching the glassfish dirs for ```tapestry-jquery*.jar```

Comment: You're right, there was a version of jQuery left in one of glassfish's folders. There are also lots of js files in `...\generated\jsp\<myTapestryProject>` folder.

Comment: You are obviously doing a dirty deploy instead of a clean deploy. You need to have a process in place where you can (periodically) do a full clean deploy.